# Listen for StreamingController And Update The List

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to keep updating the value in my player list based on what user typed in the search widget while i do streaming. I know that i can't add `add` after `where` in players but i just want you to know what i really try to do. This is my code:

```
load(StreamController controller) async {
var client = http.Client();
var req = http.Request('get', Uri.parse(PRO_PLAYERS_URL_API));
var streamRes = await client.send(req);

streamRes.stream
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(json.decoder)
    .expand((e) => e)
    .map((map) => ProPlayer.fromJson(map))
    .pipe(streamController);
}

@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
streamController = StreamController.broadcast();
streamController.stream
    .listen((player) => setState(() => players.isEmpty ? players.add(player) : players.where((p) => p.alias.startsWith(_searchController.text)).toList().add((player))));

    load(streamController);
}

@override
Widget build(Buildcontext context) {
   return Container(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
       horizontal: 6.0,
       vertical: 4.0,
     ),
      child: Column(
       children: <Widget>[
         Padding(
           padding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
           child: TextField(
             controller: _searchController,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
               hintText: 'Search for player...',
               prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
               suffixIcon: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _searchController.clear();
                 });
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              ),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
            ),
          ),
         ), Expanded(
              child: GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  childAspectRatio: 0.6,
                ),
                itemCount: players.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, int index) =>
                        ProPlayerItem(
                            player: players[index],
                            goToDetail: () => {},
                            goToSteam: () => _launchURL(
                                  players[index].profileUrl,
                                ),
                          ),
              ),
            ),
    ]
   )
  ) 
 }
```

**update:** i want the gridview keeps updating as i input the search widget while i streaming it, is that possible? i try the code above but nothing happend.

Comment: i realized that i have to add `toList()` after `where` but still no luck

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The way I understood it, you want to provide some search functionality and therefore filter a list of players depending on a given search term from the `_searchController`. But there are a lot of aspects of your sample code that I don't understand: What is the `streamController` supposed to do? What does the `load` call do? How are you integrating the search results in the `build` function? If you could explain how your current architecture is supposed to work, I'm sure it would be a lot easier to help you with your problem.

Comment: i already update the question, sir. the point is i want my gridview updating the players length and value based on what i search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why your approach isn't working**

Basically, you are trying to combine two separate functionalities into one list:
On the one hand, you want to load all the players from the web api, on the other hand you want to filter them based on some criteria.

**What to do about it**

My humble recommendation would be to separate the `players` into two list: one for all the players, the other one for the filtered players (those that should actually be displayed).

This has the benefit that both functionalities can work independently from one another: If a user changes the search query after all players loaded, it's still possible to present a useful result by filtering the original list.

```
class _SearchWidgetState extends State<SearchWidget> {
  final _searchController = TextEditingController();
  final allPlayers = <ProPlayer>[];
  List<ProPlayer> filteredPlayers = <ProPlayer>[];

  load(StreamController controller) async { ... }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    streamController = StreamController.broadcast();
    streamController.stream.listen((player) {
      allPlayers.add(player);
      _updateSearchResults();
    });

    load(streamController);
  }

  void _updateSearchResults() => setState(() {
    filteredPlayers = allPlayers
      .where((player) => player.alias.startsWith(_searchController.text))
      .toList();
  });

  @override
  Widget build(Buildcontext context) {
    return ...
      TextField(
        controller: _searchController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
          hintText: 'Search for player...',
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _updateSearchResults();
            _searchController.clear();
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
        ),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
      ),
      ...
      GridView.builder(
        ...
        itemCount: filteredPlayers.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
          final player = filteredPlayers[index];

          return ProPlayerItem(
            player: player,
            goToDetail: () => {},
            goToSteam: () => _launchURL(player.profileUrl),
          );
        }
      )
    ...;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Would you mind accepting my answer then?

Comment: sure, sorry i was forgot doing that. Thanks again